# Function with **kwargs on a class returns "unexpected argument"

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to follow this article https://towardsdatascience.com/residual-network-implementing-resnet-a7da63c7b278 but i get unexpected argument.

```
def conv_bn(in_channels, out_channels, conv, *args, **kwargs):
    return nn.Sequential(conv(in_channels, out_channels, *args, **kwargs), nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channels))
```

Running it with this function i get the right response

```
conv_bn(3, 3, nn.Conv1d, kernel_size=4, bias=False)
Sequential(
  (0): Conv1d(3, 3, kernel_size=(4,), stride=(1,), bias=False)
  (1): BatchNorm1d(3, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
)
```

But in the class i get the error:

```
class ResNetBasicBlock(ResNetResidualBlock):
    """
    Modificado para conv1d
    """
    expansion = 1
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(in_channels, out_channels, *args, **kwargs)
        self.blocks = nn.Sequential(
            conv_bn(self.in_channels, self.out_channels, conv=self.conv, bias=False,stride=self.downsampling),
            activation_func(self.activation),
            conv_bn(self.out_channels, self.expanded_channels, conv=self.conv, bias=False),
        )
dummy = torch.ones((1, 32, 224, 224))

block = ResNetBasicBlock(32, 64)
block(dummy).shape
print(block)
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-51655749b6e2> in <module>
      1 dummy = torch.ones((1, 32, 224, 224))
      2 
----> 3 block = ResNetBasicBlock(32, 64)
      4 block(dummy).shape
      5 print(block)

<ipython-input-82-67a486dfad55> in __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, *args, **kwargs)
      7         super().__init__(in_channels, out_channels, *args, **kwargs)
      8         self.blocks = nn.Sequential(
----> 9             conv_bn(self.in_channels, self.out_channels, conv=self.conv, bias=False,stride=self.downsampling),
     10             activation_func(self.activation),
     11             conv_bn(self.out_channels, self.expanded_channels, conv=self.conv, bias=False),

<ipython-input-80-0ac97ae302a5> in conv_bn(in_channels, out_channels, conv, *args, **kwargs)
      1 def conv_bn(in_channels, out_channels, conv, *args, **kwargs):
----> 2     return nn.Sequential(conv(in_channels, out_channels, *args, **kwargs), nn.BatchNorm1d(out_channels))

c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

TypeError: forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bias'
```

Comment: What's the version of (all the relevant Python packages that you're using), and the tutorial is using?

Comment: What’s the parameter signature of `self.forward`? Presumably it doesn’t take **kwargs and doesn’t have a parameter named `bias`?